# Regex Grabbing Values after specific character

Tags: regex

I have the following lines:

```
G1 X70.128 Y69.369 E11.35622
```

```
G1 X70.128 Y69.369 Z12 F12
```

```
G1 Z20
```

and all combinations there of.

For a parser i need a specfic regex that can return met values after each speficic denimoniator.

So with one regex i would like to be able to grab X,Y,Z and E from a specific input line.

is this possible?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
([Gg]0?[01]) *(([Xx]) *(-?\d+.?\d*)) *(([Yy]) *(-?\d+.?\d*))? *(([Zz]) *(-?\d+.?\d*))? *(([eE]) *(-?\d+.?\d*))? *(([fF]) *(-?\d+.?\d*))?
```

However this dictates that the order of the Letters are always as follows:

X, Y, Z, E, F

I would like that the order of the the parameters can be any. But the group of the result for example X. is always 1. and that Z is always 3.

Even when the input is: `Z12 X13` for example.

Comment: Do you mean to capture all digits after the uppercase chars? `\b[EXYZ](\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/KL6KlU/1

Comment: Yes, please check the edits i've made. hope that helps

Comment: You could write 1 alternation with all groups `\b(?:(X\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(Y\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(Z\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(E\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b` https://regex101.com/r/IgI5vK/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that one works quite well. but the match also returns the letter. Is it possible to exclude the letter from the match?

Comment: You can put the letter before the capture group `\b(?:X(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|Y(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|Z(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|E(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b` https://regex101.com/r/eFeG6A/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching the occurrences in a fixed order, you can use an alternation `|` with a case insensitive match.

To get the digits only in any order, you can match the leading character, and capture the digits in a capture group. The order of the capture groups is from left to right.

To prevent partial word matches, you can use word boundaries `\b` any of the matches by placing them in a non capture group.

```
\b(?:X(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|Y(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|Z(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|E(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `X(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Match `X`  and capture in **group 1** 1+ digits and with an optional decimal part
  - `|` Or
  - `Y(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2** for the `Y` char
  - `|` Or
  - `Z(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 3** for the `Z` char
  - `|` Or
  - `E(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 4** for the `E` char
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eFeG6A/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/MqZL66)

In Java you can loop all matches using `.find()` and a while loop:

```
String regex = "\\b(?:X(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|Y(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|Z(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|E(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))\\b";
String string = "G1 X70.128 Y69.369 e11.35622\n"
        + "G1 Z20";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (null != matcher.group(1)) System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    if (null != matcher.group(2)) System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output

```
70.128
69.369
```

etc..

Comment: In the demo this works great. But when im trying to put it in use in Java/Kotlin im getting 0 matches.

Comment: @sn0ep In Java you have to double escape the backslashes `String regex = "\\b(?:X(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|Y(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|Z(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|E(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))\\b";` and then loop all the matches checking for the specific group value. You might use for example https://ideone.com/RsmYvO

Comment: There is no need to double backslashes in Kotlin if you use triple quoted string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?i)\b(?:x(\d*\.?\d+)|y(\d*\.?\d+)|z(\d*\.?\d+)|e(\d*\.?\d+)|f(\d*\.?\d+))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NH9mYu/2). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `x(\d*\.?\d+)|` - `x` and an int or float value captured into Group 1, or
  - `y(\d*\.?\d+)|` - `y` and an int or float value captured into Group 2, or
  - `z(\d*\.?\d+)|` - `z` and an int or float value captured into Group 3, or
  - `e(\d*\.?\d+)|` - `e` and an int or float value captured into Group 4, or
  - `f(\d*\.?\d+)`  - `f` and an int or float value captured into Group 5
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - a word boundary.

In Kotlin, you need to use the pattern with `.findAll`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val regex = """(?i)\b
        |(?:x(\d*\.?\d+)|
        |y(\d*\.?\d+)|
        |z(\d*\.?\d+)|
        |e(\d*\.?\d+)|
        |f(\d*\.?\d+))\b
    """.trimMargin().toRegex(RegexOption.COMMENTS)
    val matches = regex.findAll("G1 Z0.350 F7800.000").map { it.destructured.toList() }
    matches.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
    // => [, , 0.350, , ][, , , , 7800.000]
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Nm2Nyh)